# pgbouncer vs postgres hba config file

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have `postgres` with hba configuration file and `pgbouncer` for connection pooling.

I want to connect to `pgbouncer` (instead of `postgres`) only by changing the port number of the connection string (`6543` instead of `5432`). Both `postgres` and `pgbouncer` run on the same server.

So far, I've been able to have `pgbouncer` run with its own hba file with duplicated user/password. It's not maintainable (or at least very painful) to manually sync `postgres` and `pgbouncer` user/password.

Is there any way I can make `pgbouncer` forward user/password login attempts to `postgres` as-is? Or am I trying to work my conf against the way things should go?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of pgbouncer do you use? Starting from 1.6 it is able to load users/passwords directly from database. You just need to specify "auth_query"
 in your config file. 
https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html